# Unable to set property [lockingModel] on object [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender] using value [MinimalLock]

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am getting this error in my C# application. I am using log4net as a logging tool.

Here is my app.config file:

```xml
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type ="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="myLogger" />
    </root>
    <appender name="myLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="File" value="C:\MyApp\Logs\appLog.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <lockingModel value="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

Note: `type` instead of `value`.

Comment: I still get an error message in log4net debug output on the console. `Object type [log4net.Appender.FileAppender] is not assignable to type [log4net.Appender.FileAppender+LockingModelBase]. There are no acceptable type conversions.` and `Failed to create object to set param: lockingModel`

Comment: maybe it would be best to post separate question including your configuration. I cannot say what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen when there is an XML element in the appender configuration but not a matching property in the appender.   For example the `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` does not have a property for "LockingModel", so if it's included in the configxml as it is in the above examples, the `XmlConfigurator` will report the same error as in the title