# log4net not working, no file created, getting exception message

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm trying to get log4net to work in a legacy application but I'm getting this exception when it starts (from DbgView):

> log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Object type
>   [log4net.Appender.FileAppender] is not assignable to type
>   [log4net.Appender.FileAppender+LockingModelBase]. There are no
>   acceptable type conversions.
>
> log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Failed to create object to set
>   param: lockingModel

What does this mean and, more importantly, how do I silence this error and make it work?  This is on an Outlook plugin if that makes any difference. Here's my app.config file (some non-essential parts redacted due to confidentiality):

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <param name="File" value="c:\errlog.txt" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>    
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.Net"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.Net"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Net.Cache">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.Net"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
        <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
        <!--add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/-->
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="System.Net"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="network.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I've found a number of other posts saying that adding the line `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` should fix this, but it does not fix anything.  The end result I'm looking for is a log file that has information in it that will allow me to debug this application, how do I get this thing to work?

Also, I have read every other related question on stackoverflow (several dozen of them), and this is the only other one that I've seen that even has the same exception message and there is no answer provided that is working for me: [Unable to set property [lockingModel] on object [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender] using value [MinimalLock]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076727/unable-to-set-property-lockingmodel-on-object-log4net-appender-rollingfileapp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the compiler at hand, however when I compare the plain text configuration with my working configuration set, I believe you miss the

```
<file value="PATHTOFILE\error.log" />
```

instread you have

```
<param name="File" value="PATHTOFILE\error.log" />
```

This difference looks like the possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

You save something to root directory of C: , please check if you have the privilege to do so. I met the same problem but I solved with saving the file to D: or some folders in C:
have a try of this under root configuration:

```
<!--log to file-->
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add
        name="textWriterTraceListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="C:\Users\Klaus\Documents\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```